# Atm program xUnit unit test

Tags: c#, xunit

I have these 3 methods for ATM mock program.

```
    public decimal CheckBalance(BankAccount account)
    {
        return account.AccountBalance;
    }

    public void Deposit(BankAccount account, BankTransaction bankTransaction)
    {
        account.AccountBalance += bankTransaction.TransactionAmount;
    }

    public void Withdraw(BankAccount account, BankTransaction bankTransaction)
    {
        if(bankTransaction.TransactionAmount > account.AccountBalance)
        {
            throw new Exception("Withdraw failed. Transaction amount is more than account balance.");
        }

        account.AccountBalance -= bankTransaction.TransactionAmount;
    }
```

And here are my xUnit unit test methods. The test data is in-memory for this version.

```
    [Theory, MemberData(nameof(CheckBalanceShouldReturnValidBalanceAmount_Data))]
    public void CheckBalanceShouldReturnValidBalanceAmount(BankAccount account, decimal accountBalance)
    {
        // Act
        var balance = _atm.CheckBalance(account);

        // Assert
        Assert.Equal(accountBalance, balance);
    }

    [Theory, MemberData(nameof(DepositShouldPass_Data))]
    public void DepositShouldPass(BankAccount account, BankTransaction bankTransaction, BankAccount accountExpected)
    {
        // Act
        _atm.Deposit(account, bankTransaction);
        var balance = _atm.CheckBalance(account);

        // Assert
        Assert.Equal(accountExpected.AccountBalance, balance);
    }

    [Theory, MemberData(nameof(WithdrawShouldPass_Data))]
    public void WithdrawShouldPass(BankAccount account, BankTransaction bankTransaction, BankAccount accountExpected)
    {
        // Act
        _atm.Withdraw(account, bankTransaction);
        var balance = _atm.CheckBalance(account);

        // Assert
        Assert.Equal(accountExpected.AccountBalance, balance);
    }

    [Theory, MemberData(nameof(WithdrawAmountMoreThanBalanceShouldFail_Data))]
    public void WithdrawAmountMoreThanBalanceShouldFail(BankAccount account, BankTransaction bankTransaction)
    {            
        // Assert and Act
        var exception = Assert.Throws<Exception>(() => _atm.Withdraw(account, bankTransaction));
        Assert.Equal("Withdraw failed. Transaction amount is more than account balance.", 
            exception.Message);
    }
```

All tests passed successfully. Any comments on coding style of unit test?

**Edited After Answer with extra class:**

```
namespace XUnitSample.ClassLib.Models
{
    public class BankAccount
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int BankAccountNo { get; set; }
        public decimal AccountBalance { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace XUnitSample.ClassLib.Models
{
    public class BankTransaction
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public decimal TransactionAmount { get; set; }
        public TransactionTypeEnum TransactionType { get; set; }
    }

    public enum TransactionTypeEnum
    {
        Deposit, Withdraw, ThirdPartyTransfer
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your mock ATM class literally named `_atm`?!  Or is it a non-static class that you have assigned to an instance named `_atm`?  Either way, I don't like it and find the `_atm` class to be useless in your limited example.

The `BankAccount` class, which you do not share, should have a `Deposit` and `Withdraw` method, both accepting a `BankTransaction` as a input argument.  You should include validation of a particular transaction within each method, i.e. do not accept a deposit of negative amount.  You also do not share `BankTransaction` with us.

`CheckBalance` is not needed, as you would just as easily show the `BankAccount.AccountBalance` property.  Also the property name could be shortened to `Balance` since it is the balance of the bank account.

Comment: My ATM class is named as `AtmApp`. Yeah, it is a non-static class and I instantiate it in my constructor at this `AtmAppTest` class and name the instance as `_atm`. I have added `BankAccount` and `BankTransaction` class at my original post. But these class is anemic. Oh this means `Deposit` and `Withraw` method should moved to `BankAccount`. Okay, thanks.